# Find element by index in different xml subtree

Tags: xml, reactjs, xpath, webdriver

I am looking for the solution for the next task:
Given: https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/example-object-data.html, there is a table built on divs.
There is elements like `<div class="fixedDataTableCellLayout_main public_fixedDataTableCell_main" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; left: 0px;"></div>`
which contain cells value.
They are divided by two different subtrees in `<div class="fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroupWrapper" style="height: 50px; left: 0px;"></div>`.
Three of columns in one and the rest in another block.
I am looking for possibility to find all values from a column.
The way //div[contains(@class, 'public_fixedDataTableCell_main')][1] doesn't work due to it finds in parallel in both subtrees.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all names from the first column :

```
//*[@class="public_fixedDataTableCell_cellContent"]/a/text()
```

Comment: it retrives a text from all cells, not only from first column

Comment: No, only the first col, but with the name and email. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
//*[@class='fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroupWrapper'][1]//*[@class='public_fixedDataTableCell_cellContent']/a/text()
```

XPath Indexing

**Q :** What does //td[2] mean?

**A :** All td elements in that page (document), that are second child of their parent.